# Reading txt file and adding the contents to a Tkinter Listbox Python

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, text-files, file-handling

I am wondering how one adds the contents of a `.txt` file to a `Tkinter Listbox`?

Let's say I had a file called `test.txt` and I wanted to add the contents of it to a Listbox named `Lb`, how would I do it? Below is an example of what I have tried - to help you understand the question!

**Contents of `test.txt`**:

```
Apple
Cherry
Beetroot
```

**My Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

Lb = Listbox(root)
Lb.grid()
f = open("test.txt","r")
for x in f:
    Lb.insert(END,x)
    print(x)
f.close()
```

The Traceback is blank, showing the file is not opening properly, but I don't know where I have an error in my code. The Listbox should contain apple, cherry and beetroot on seperate lines/entries. But it is completely blank, likely because there was no Traceback from above, seeming as the `.txt` file wasn't opening properly. What have I done wrong? And how can I correct my code to do as I explained in the beginning of my answer?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: Your code works fine for me, except for the fact that you aren't calling `mainloop` to keep the window open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Bryan said. Add `root.mainloop()` to the end to keep your application running:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
Lb = Listbox(root)
Lb.grid()
f = open("test.txt","r")
for x in f:
    Lb.insert(END,x)
    print(x)
f.close()
root.mainloop()
```